# how to deform image?

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios4

Hi Friends
 I Want to make a simple gaming Application in which the user hit the car and car breaks from that point means the image get little deformed when the user hit the car image. I know everything could be possible with using of lots of images and get change when user hit that car image but i don't want to use so many images.

is there any solution for this , how can i deform the image ..sorry for my English but , here i paste a link of the game that is on flash and this is what i exactly want..

http://www.playgecogames.com/file.php?f=657&a=popup

please respond soon 
thanks

Comment: any specific reason why you don't want to use images?? cause thats the easiest way.. and you can have a car divided into parts and have images for each part.. so that when the user hits at one place, you only change the next (more deformed) image of that part of the car not the entire car's image.. i suppose thats what the online game in your link does.. image editing algorithms aren't very simple to implement..

Comment: thanks 4 reply friend..but is there any method to deform images a little ...using mutiple hundred of image nt actually making sense to me.

Comment: The Flash game you have linked in your question obviously does not deform the image data but simply uses plenty of variations of the same car devided into smaller parts of it. Using image editing algorithms will hardly ever give you good looking results. The only other option is to use OpenGL and very high detailed models of the car.

Comment: yes friend in this link flash uses 600 image sof the car ...but i want to make it possibe with single image is it possible..i already did that using many images and divide the car into smaller peices and just change image after every hit

Comment: You would have to use finite elements physics for achieving at least somewhat realistic results. Imagine all the different materials used for a car - just compare glass against tin - that is going to be a lot of mathematics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't say if this is in 2D or 3D, or what techniques you're going to use.

If you're implementing the game using OpenGL, it's fairly straightforward.  The object can be made up of a regular mesh, with the image as a texture mapped to the mesh.  When the user hits the object, you just deform the mesh.

A simple method would be to take a vector in the direction of the hit, displace the nearest vertex by an amount proportional to the force of the strike, and then fan out in to deform the rest of the mesh in decreasing amounts.  By deforming the mesh, the image texture will be rendered with all the dents or deformations you like.

If you want to to this without OpenGL and just straight images, you could use image resampling to simulate the effect.  You have your original pristine image which is 'filtered' to make up the resulting image.  At first there are no deformations so you copy the original image verbatim.  Each time the user hits the object, you can add a deformation using a filter or transform within a local region of interest.  This function would resample the source image in a distorted manner, causing it to look like the object is damaged.

If you look up some good books on game development, you'll find a great range of approaches to object collisions, deformations and so on.

Answer (score 1):

If you know a bit about image processing technics here is the documentation for accessing the pixels of the image :
[Apple Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1509/_index.html)

You also have libraries for this such as this one : 

[simple-iphone-image-processing](http://code.google.com/p/simple-iphone-image-processing/)

But for what you want to do this might not be the easiest way. What I would suggest is that you divide the car into several images depending on what areas can be impacted. Then you just change the image corresponding to the damaged zone each time the car is hit.

Comment: i also follow the same friend , i break the car into several parts and after every hit i just change image this is easy and it show like i hit the car and scratch occour at that point.....but i dont want that i want that i nt to use so many images

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use the cocos2d effects http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/wiki/doku.php/prog_guide%3aeffects  +  multiple images. Because there are many parts which drops after the player kick the car. Like when user kick the side mirror you should change the car image with without side mirror car image.

Answer (score 0):

The person that has made that flash game used around 4 images to display the car. If you want the game to be in 2d, the easiest way is to draw the car, cut it into about 4 pieces (: left side + right side (duplicate of the left side) hood and roof).

If you want to "really" deform the car you'll have to use a 3d engine like openGLES.

Id really suggest doing it in 2d :)

Answer (score -1):

I suggest having a look at the [cocos2d](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/) game engine. You can modify images with effects, which are applied using a virtual grid. Have a look at the [effects page](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/wiki/doku.php/prog_guide%3aeffects) in their programming guide.